# Better way to prove the geometric mean is always in between?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The geometric mean of two numbers is defined as $$c = \sqrt{ab}$$ and there have been times where I'm reading an article/textbook and the author says that $c = \sqrt{ab}$ implies $a \lt c \lt b$ ($a,b,c \gt 0$) without any proof. I tried to prove it myself and came up with a batch of inequalities. Assuming that $a \lt b$ $$c \lt a \implies c^2 \lt a^2 \implies \frac{c^2}{b}\lt \frac{a^2}{b} \lt \frac{a^2}{a} = a $$ $$c^2 \lt ab \implies c \lt \sqrt{ab}$$ which is a contradiction, so $c \ge a$. Then repeating the process, $$c \gt b \implies c^2 \gt b^2 \implies \frac{c^2}{a} \gt \frac{b^2}{a} \gt \frac{b^2}{b} = b$$  $$c^2 \gt ab \implies c \gt \sqrt{ab}$$ which proves that $c \le b$. This gives the conclusion that $$c = \sqrt{ab} \implies c \in [a,b]$$ But is there a quicker or more clever way to prove that the geometric mean of two positive numbers lies between those numbers?

Comment: I think that you mean that if $~0 < a,b,c~$and $~c = \sqrt{ab}~$ then $~c~$ must be between $~a,b.~$  That is, if $~a < b,~$ then you must have that $~a < c < b.~$  This is easily proven by considering that $~c = \sqrt{ab}~$ and that $~a^2 < ab < b^2.~$  The function $~f(x) = x^2~$ is a strictly increasing function on $~\Bbb{R^+}.$

Comment: Hint: $\;c^2 - a^2 = a(b-a)\,$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since everything is positive, the inequality $a<c<b$ is equivalent to $a^2<c^2<b^2$, or $a^2<ab<b^2$. Since $a<b$, it follows that $a\cdot a<a\cdot b<b\cdot b$, so your result follows from that.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a typo. Did you mean $a < c < b$, where $b > a > 0$?

If this is the case, we can proceed as follows.

First we shall prove that $a < c$. Indeed, that is the case:
\begin{align*}
0 < a < b & \Rightarrow \sqrt{a} < \sqrt{b} \Rightarrow a < \sqrt{ab} = c
\end{align*}
Similarly, we do also have the other inequality:
\begin{align*}
b > a > 0 \Rightarrow \sqrt{b} > \sqrt{a} \Rightarrow b > \sqrt{ab} = c
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo!

Comment: @MumboJumbo you are welcome! :)